# Generic function for modifying scalars and slices in place

Tags: rust

I don't understand some basics in Rust. I want to compute a function `sinc(x)`, with `x` being a scalar or a slice, which modifies the values in place. I can implement methods for both types, calling them with `x.sinc()`, but I find it more convenient (and easier to read in long formulas) to make a function, e.g. `sinc(&mut x)`. So how do you do that properly?

```
pub trait ToSinc<T> {
    fn sinc(self: &mut Self) -> &mut Self;
}

pub fn sinc<T: ToSinc<T>>(y: &mut T) -> &mut T {
    y.sinc()
}

impl ToSinc<f64> for f64 {
    fn sinc(self: &mut Self) -> &mut Self {
        *self = // omitted
        self
    }
}

impl<'a> ToSinc<&'a mut [f64]> for &'a mut [f64] {
    fn sinc(self: &mut Self) -> &mut Self {
        for yi in (**self).iter_mut() { ... }
        self
    }
}
```

This seems to work, but isn't the "double indirection"  in the last `impl` costly? I also thought about doing

```
pub trait ToSinc<T> {
    fn sinc(self: Self) -> Self;
}

pub fn sinc<T: ToSinc<T>>(y: T) -> T {
    y.sinc()
}

impl<'a> ToSinc<&'a mut f64> for &'a mut f64 {
    fn sinc(self) -> Self {
        *self = ...
        self
    }
}

impl<'a> ToSinc<&'a mut [f64]> for &'a mut [f64] {
    fn sinc(self) -> Self {
        for yi in (*self).iter_mut() { ... }
        self
    }
}
```

This also works, the difference is that if `x` is a `&mut [f64]` slice, I can call `sinc(x)` instead of `sinc(&mut x)`. So I have the impression there is less indirection going on in the second one, and I think that's good. Am I on the wrong track here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I find it highly unlikely that any differences from the double-indirection won't be inlined away *in this case*, but you're right that the second is to be preferred.

You have `ToSinc<T>`, but don't use `T`. Drop the template parameter.

That said, `ToSinc` should almost certainly be by-value for `f64`s:

```
impl ToSinc for f64 {
    fn sinc(self) -> Self {
        ...
    }
}
```

You might also want `ToSinc for &mut [T] where T: ToSinc`.

---

You might well say, "ah - one of these is by value, and the other by mutable reference; isn't that inconsistent?"

The answer depends on what you're actually intend the trait to be used as.

#### An interface for `sinc`-able types

If your interface represents those types that you can run `sinc` over, as traits of this kind are intended to be used, the goal would be to write functions

```
fn do_stuff<T: ToSinc>(value: T) { ... }
```

Now note that **the interface is by-value**. `ToSinc` takes `self` and returns `Self`: that is a value-to-value function. In fact, even when `T` is instantiated to some mutable reference, like `&mut [f64]`, **the function is unable to observe *any* mutation to the underlying memory**.

In essence, these functions treat the underlying memory as an allocation source, and to value transformations on the data held in these allocations, much like a `Box → Box` operation is a by-value transformation of heap memory. Only the *caller* is able to observe mutations to the memory, but even then implementations which treat their input as a value type will return a pointer that prevents needing to access the data in this memory. The caller can just treat the source data as opaque in the same way that an allocator is.

Operations which depend on mutability, like writing to buffers, should probably not be using such an interface. Sometimes to support these cases it makes sense to build a mutating basis and a convenient by-value accessor. [`ToString`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/trait.ToString.html) is an interesting example of this, as it's just a wrapper over [`Display`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/trait.Display.html).

```
pub trait ToSinc: Sized {
    fn sinc_in_place(&mut self);
    fn sinc(mut self) -> Self {
        self.sinc_in_place();
        self
    }
}
```

where `impl`s mostly just implement `sinc_in_place` and users tend to prefer `sinc`.

#### As fakery for ad-hoc overloading

In this case, one doesn't care if the trait is actually usable generically, or even that it's consistent. `sinc("foo")` might do a sing and dance, for all we care.

As such, although the trait is needed it should be defined as weakly as possible:

```
pub trait Sincable {
    type Out;
    fn sinc(self) -> Self::Out;
}
```

Then your function is far more generic:

```
pub fn sinc<T: Sincable>(val: T) -> T::Out {
    val.sinc()
}
```

To implement a by-value function you do

```
impl Sincable for f64 {
    type Out = f64;
    fn sinc(self) -> f64 {
        0.4324
    }
}
```

and a by-mut-reference one is just

```
impl<'a, T> Sincable for &'a mut [T]
    where T: Sincable<Out=T> + Copy
{
    type Out = ();
    fn sinc(self) {
        for i in self {
            *i = sinc(*i);
        }
    }
}
```

since `()` is the default empty type. This acts just like an ad-hoc overloading would.

[Playpen example of emulated ad-hoc overloading.](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=5c6302193104f2f48c36&version=stable)

Comment: Thanks, I removed the template parameter, works well. Regarding your second suggestions, the problem is that self is not mutable. I could return a new value, which in principle works, it's just that the syntax gets inconsistent. Sinc(x=scalar) then doesn't modify x, whereas sinc(x=slice) does. On the other hand, what I have in the second snippet is also cumbersome, because I have to write sinc(&mut (x=scalar)), but sinc(x=slice). So the &mut is necessary for the scalar but not for the slice.

Comment: @poidl I've made my answer a lot more detailed. Hopefully this explains things better.

Comment: great, thanks for your time putting this together, I feel like I will learn a lot from this!